# Enabling and disabling dragging markers by checkbox

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/T6Up6/1/). How can I make the markers draggable when the check box is unchecked? All markers have their own associated checkbox, which means that user can lock each marker which they want (not all together).

Initially all markers are unchecked when they loaded to page. And finally I need to change the icon when the marker checked as lock.

```
  var contentString = ' -- Lock <input name="your_name" value="your_value" type="checkbox">';
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "" });
  var data = {
        "markers": [{
                "latitude": 11.606503,
                "longitude": 122.712637,
                "title": "Copenhagen"
            }, {
                "latitude": 11.585988,
                "longitude": 122.757084,
                "title": "Barcelona"
            }
        ]
    };
    locations.length = 0;
    for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude, data.markers[p].longitude),
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: "marker " + p,
            id: p
        });

        bindMarker(marker);
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, data.markers[p].title);
    }

    function bindMarker(marker) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
   marker.setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        });
    }
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(strDescription + contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
}
});
```

### Update

Code:

```
  function bindMarkerDrag(marker){
        google.maps.event.addListener(checkbox, "click", function(){
            draggable: false
         //marker.setClickable(checkbox.checked);
      });
        }
```

then I add the following inside the loop:

```
 bindMarkerDrag(marker);
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/T6Up6/2/), but it is not working.

Comment: Add another listener that listens for dragstart and check the checkbox value.

Comment: Thanks putvande, can you please let me know should I add the moistener to marker again? like: google.maps.event.addListener(marker if so ? what action should I put fir checkbox click?

Comment: I tried to add some code which didn't work , can you please take a look at update to see if I am doing correct? Thanka

Comment: Please take a look at the demo on update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to add `checkbox.checked = !marker.getDraggable();` in your marker click event listener. Not in the checkbox event listener.

```
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.checked = !marker.getDraggable();
checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
    marker.setDraggable(!this.checked);
});
```

1. Create the checbox
2. Check it or not if the marker is draggable or not
3. Manage the checkbox click event

Answer (score 0):

You could something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(e){
    marker.setDraggable(document.getElementById('checkbox').checked);
});
```

This will set the draggable property to false or true before you start dragging (if you put it on the `dragstart` event, you will have a slight delay.)
Replace the id `checkbox` with the one you need.

Comment: Thanks but where do I have to use this , inside the same function?

Comment: Yes inside `bindMarker` I think.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code!! I have updated buildInfoWindow function to meet your requirements.

```
var map;
var locations = [];
var contentString = "--";
var infowindows = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.610707, 122.740089);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        draggableCursor: 'move',
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var data = {
        "markers": [{
                "latitude": 11.606503,
                "longitude": 122.712637,
                "title": "Copenhagen"
            }, {
                "latitude": 11.585988,
                "longitude": 122.757084,
                "title": "Barcelona"
            }
        ]
    };
    locations.length = 0;
    for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].latitude, data.markers[p].longitude),
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: "marker " + p,
            id: p
        });
        var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "" });
        bindMarker(marker);
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, data.markers[p].title, p);
        bindMarkerDrag(marker);
    }

    function bindMarker(marker) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
   marker.setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
        });
    }
    function bindMarkerDrag(marker){

    }


    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription, p) {
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, 'click', function() {
     var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
        marker.setDraggable(!this.checked);
    });
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = strDescription + contentString + "<br /> Lock             drag:  &nbsp;";
        div.appendChild(checkbox);
    infowindow.setContent(div);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    infowindows[p]= infowindow;
});
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindows[p].open(map, marker);
});
}

});
```

Comment: if you click or onclick  a box several time it is not functioning properly

Comment: if you check or uncheck the checkbox for second time it is going to change state of all checkboxes

Comment: @MonaCoder, I have updated my answer. The issue was that content was getting created on every click and single infowindow instance was used on all markers!! Hope it helps now.

Comment: yeah but still same thing happening.it is ok until the info windows is closing by clicking on other marker but if for what reason which I don't know it stats toggling check box between all boxes

Comment: Based on http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/T6Up6/3/ you simply need to add `checkbox.checked = !marker.getDraggable();` in your marker click event listener. This way you reset your checkbox state every time you click a marker.

Comment: Hi MrUpsidown, Thanks for your comment but Still facing to same issue: here: http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/T6Up6/4/ As you can I added the code you said to the code but still same thing happens

Comment: Mona Coder, I have updated my post again. Every marker has different infowindow instance now to preserve states. Could not thoroughly check due to lack of time.

Comment: You didn't add it at the right place. You don't need different infowindow instances! Please check my answer.

Comment: In most cases, you don't need to have multiple infowindow objects. If you have 2 markers, that's fine. But what if you have hundreds? The infowindow object is made so that you can change its content and bind it to any marker.