# create of check box on map and adding event for checked or not using div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

- i tried to create check box on map using div `document.createElement('div');`

  - how to give checked event and calling function,

    `function initializ() {
    var mapOptions = {
    center: mylatlong,
    .........
    ........
    var optionControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    optionControlDiv.id='options';
    var optionControl = new OptionControl(optionControlDiv, map);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(optionControlDiv);
    .....
    }`

    // and my check box creation code is

    `function OptionControl(controlDiv, map) {
    var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI.type="checkbox";
    controlUI.onclick = "checkboxclicked(this)";
    ............
    }`

    // then how to call function how to do event above code not working.
  - help with sample code

Comment: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI,'click',function(){checkboxclicked(this);});`

Comment: a type="checkbox" applies to an `<input>` element.

Comment: thanks, but i get same output of checked value even i un-checked `alert($('#checkboxId').is(':checked')) (i added id as controlUI.id="checkboxId")`

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878267/enabling-and-disabling-dragging-markers-by-checkbox/20903160#20903160) it might help to understand how to deal with the checkbox.